# replace a container with viewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments

I made a navigation drawer, as you know the navigation drawer will have a container where all layouts are inflated.
I need to have a scrollable tabs on one of the pages. I am having problem with inflating the viewPager layout into the container which is implemented in the following fragment class:

```
public class Pager extends Fragment {

ViewPager viewPager = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.fragment_pager);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(fragmentManager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(myAdapter);
}
}


class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

Fragment fragment = null;

public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position){
        case 0:
            fragment = new MapFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new RegisterRestaurants();
            break;
    }
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return 2;
}
```

}

layout fragment_pager:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Hope someone can help, I browsed the internet and all tutorials were doing it from within a FragmentActivity but in my situation I have to do it inside a Fragment

logcat output:

```
02-25 00:16:17.814  18197-18197/com.example.famfelimban.mydiet E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f090054 (com.example.famfelimban.mydiet:id/container) for fragment Pager{4329bcb0 #1 id=0x7f090054}
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:939)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:454)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using     match_parent for both width
and height to consume the full space available. -->    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
 <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</FrameLayout>


<!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
     languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
     If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
     android:layout_gravity="left" instead. -->
<!-- The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container. -->
<fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:name="com.example.famfelimban.mydiet.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>'
```

Comment: can you include error message from the logs please

Comment: Your id is called 'container' in the xml and you are trying to reference it via 'pager'. Reading and understanding the logcat is your best friend.

Comment: well pager and container are totally different, the container is where the layouts are inflated. pager is the Pager class layout. I guess the problem is that i am trying to use navigation drawer besides the scrollable tabs
Check the new updated code where the container tag is used @toidiu

Comment: check that the import statements are for ViewPager are using the support version in your java code. Can you also provide the entire  layout fragment_pager file please

Answer (score 0):

You can do next:

```
public class Pager extends Fragment {

    ViewPager viewPager = null;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pager, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.container);

        MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter();
        viewPager.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    }

    class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        Fragment fragment = null;

        public MyAdapter() {
            super(getChildFragmentManager());
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    fragment = new MapFragment();
                break;
                case 1:
                    fragment = new RegisterRestaurants();
                    break;
            }
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return 2;
        }
    }
}

public class PagerActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pager);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.holder, new Pager())
                    .commit();
        }
    }
}
```

fragment_pager.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                   android:id="@+id/pager"
                                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

activity_pager.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/holder"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

</FrameLayout>
```

**EDIT**

activity_pager.xml can have next:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</FrameLayout>

<fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
          android:tag="navtag"
          android:layout_width="240dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_gravity="left"
          android:name="com.example.NavigationFragment" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for replaying. I already have MainActivity that extends the ActionBarActivity where i implement the navigation drawer. So i cant use the PagerActivity because the fragmentManager won't accept to replace a fragment with an activity if you got what i mean. @StanislavBodnar

Comment: You can add similar logic into your ActionBarActivity - just do main view as some of ViewGroup where you can add your fragment that incapsulate ViewPager.